# ReactJS - Pagination/Load More from a REST API

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, reactjs

**In Short:** I am fetching X JSON Objects from an API, but I only want to display the first 20 Objects, and then have the possibility to fetch another 20 Objects if the user decides to. Whats the best way to do that?

**Here is my component, where I am fetching all the teams on componentDidMount and then getting all the JSON objects from my reducer:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { APIManager, DateUtils, YouTubeID } from '../../utils'
import actions from '../../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import  { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


class teams extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  selectTeam(team, event){
  event.preventDefault()
  this.props.selectTeam(team)
 }

  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.teams != null){
      return
    }
    this.props.fetchTeams()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.teams != null){
      return
    }
    this.props.fetchTeams()
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="wrap">
        <div style={{height: '65px'}} className="hero hero-teams-2">
        <div className="hero-inner group">
          <h1 className="center title-long">
            <strong>Pro CS:GO </strong>
            Teams
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

  <div style={{paddingTop: '0px'}} id="wrap-inner">
    <div id="content" role="main">

<div id="main" className="main-full">
  <div className="group">


    <div style={{marginLeft: '150px'}} className="portal-group designers">

      <h3 style={{marginLeft: '40%'}} className="jump">
        <a href="#">Select A Team</a>
      </h3>

      <div className="scrollable-content-container">
        <ol className="portal-list-members debutants scrollable">

{(this.props.teams == null) ? null :
  this.props.teams.map((team, i) => {

    return (
      <li onClick={this.selectTeam.bind(this, team.teamname)} key={i} className="group">
        <h3>
        <Link to={'/team'} style={{color: '#444', textTransform: 'capitalize'}} className="url hoverable" href="#">
          <img style={{height: '160px', width: '160px'}} className="photo" src={"images/"+team.image}/>
        {team.teamname}
      </Link>
      </h3>
    </li>
    )
  })
}
</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    )
  }
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      teams: state.players.teams
  }
}

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    selectTeam: (team) => dispatch(actions.selectTeam(team)),
    fetchTeams: (params) => dispatch(actions.fetchTeams(params))
  }
}

export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(teams)
```

**Mongo Query**

```
router.get('/liveTeams', function(req, res, next){
  Team.find({})
  .where('status', 'live')
    .sort({timestamp : -1})
  .exec(function(err, results){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'success',
      results: results
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Either fetch them all and slice the array before you set this.props.teams to the result. Or only fetch 20 at the time. You'll probably have to edit the `fetchTeams()` function somewhere.

Comment: There could be between 100 and 1000 teams, so I only want to fetch whats necessary - I am using MongoDb to generate the Json objects, so maybe I should be going it there?

Comment: Yeah, just edit your query to mongo to only fetch record 1 to 20. Then have a variable to store that the last record fetched was record 20. Then next 'page', fetch record var + 1 to var + 20 and set var to var + 20. (20 to 40, var becomes 40; 40 to 60 var becomes 60) Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! I am not quite sure how to fetch the records from 1 to 20. Right now my query looks like in the edit i made. How would you fetch from record from 1-20 like you explained?

Comment: db.foo.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(20);

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a extra method: `.limit(20)` you can add so you only get max 20 records back.

You can then also use the `.skip()` method to skip over the previous records.
So if the sorting is Always the same, you would use:

`Team.find({}).where('status', 'live').sort({timestamp : -1}).skip(0).limit(20)`
the first time.

The next call will be:
`Team.find({}).where('status', 'live').sort({timestamp : -1}).skip(20).limit(20)`

and so on.

Comment: So in componentDidMount I would fetch the Json data with the Team.find({}).where('status', 'live').sort({timestamp : -1}).skip(0).limit(20) query, then I would have a Load more button at the end of the page that when clicked would fetch data from the Team.find({}).where('status', 'live').sort({timestamp : -1}).skip(20).limit(20) query. If iam understanding you right?

Comment: Indeed. Just use a variable you add to the params passed to the query for use inside `.step( params.someStepName )` so you only need to have one version. Or add another parameter to fetchTeams, if you can't reuse the params object you already have.

Comment: Could you give an example, I am not quite sure what you mean? :)